# Programming for the Apple infared remote controls

Tags: cocoa, macos, remote-control, infrared

How do I get started with programming for the Apple infared remote control?

To start with, I only intend to support one control, and one type of receiver, that on the current unibody MacBooks.

What I mean by programming, is, how do I get started with writing an OSX, preferably Cocoa if there are APIs, app which intercepts commands from the control, and then sends commands to the OS.

For example, as a start, I'd like to be able to simply pick up a key press from the remote control, and then emit a keyboard command to the OS.

Like, say I've got this listener app running,  if you press the menu button, and you're in the textedit app, it prints out the letter "a" for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some searching around has revealed:

- https://github.com/martinkahr/apple_remote_control
- http://www.iospirit.com/developers/

Other resources:

- http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?UsingTheAppleRemoteControl
- a [video presentation](http://mark.aufflick.com/blog/2009/05/05/adding-apple-remote-support-to-your-cocoa-app) and [the slides](http://www.slideshare.net/markaufflick/adding-apple-remote-support-to-your-cocoa-app)

If I find more I'll edit my answer.