# OSX remote control events

Tags: ios, macos, remote-control

I've been searching for a while now and I haven't found anything equivalent to the iPhone UIApplication method beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents in order to send events from my earpods to the OSX app. Is this even possible with osx apps?

Comment: Have you seen `http://stackoverflow.com/a/4976507/22147`?